# Woo-commerce plug-in that allows continue shopping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

Hello I would like to as if somebody knows of a woo-commerce plug-in or a way to implement a functionality to a wordpress website where after user click add to cart button to be asked in a pop-up go to cart or continue shoping on the same page or on some other page with similar products ? Same functionality that is available on amazon.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Popup Cart Lite for WooCommerce' plugin to add same functionality in your site.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-woocart-popup-lite/